# What planet is the Death Star orbiting in Andor

Tags: star-wars, andor

In the season finale of *Andor* we see the Death Star being built while in orbit over a planet. What planet is it?

I have seen some people saying Scarif, but is this confirmed anywhere? Based in what we see in *Rogue One* I didn’t get the impression that the Death Star was ever constructed there as it seemed to be in another location when the dish was set in place and Scarif didn’t seem to have the infrastructure to support construction of that scale.

I know the Death Star moved a few times during construction. Do any of the confirmed systems it was in match with this planet?

[image]

Comment: It's definitely not Geonosis. The Death Star was moved to orbit around Scarif circa 9BBY because Saw Gerrera nearly discovered its existence. Most things I've found say it's Scarif, which makes sense, but AFAIK the episode didn't say it outright. Maybe the audio description does? They did that with the Dark Troopers in Mando S2.

Comment: Could be a forest moon. The forest moon of Andor.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - The audio description does indeed confirm that it's Scarif

Comment: The only right answer here for true fans is the Maw.

Comment: Future asteroid belt A?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn *cough*DESPAYRE*cough*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The official audio description for the episode indicates that the Death Star is under construction over Scarif.

> *The outer space construction site pulls away to reveal numerous similar arrays, connecting into interlocking hexagons in a single section of a concave outer rim. Two TIE fighters scream past the telescoping module of interconnected components. Together they point toward the gaping hole of the Death Star's unfinished superlaser, **with the battle station orbiting Scarif***.

Answer (score 8):

It's most likely Scarif. Earlier in the series, in the episode "Aldhani", Lonni mentions in an ISB meeting that there's been increased traffic near Scarif. According to the [starwars.com trivia gallery](https://www.starwars.com/andor-s1-e4-trivia-gallery?image_id=5e9d99f9ab34eebd6b4f2a72) for the episode:

> The Abrion sector and Scarif are mentioned in Supervisor Lonni Jung's ISB update as a site of increased traffic. There's a good reason for that, as revealed in Rogue One: A Star Wars Story: **Scarif is the current construction site of the Death Star.**
>
> <sub>(Source: https://www.starwars.com/andor-s1-e4-trivia-gallery?image_id=5e9d99f9ab34eebd6b4f2a72; emphasis added)</sub>

This entry in the supplementary materials for the show at least shows that it was the showrunners' intent that, as of partway through the first season, the Death Star was being constructed over Scarif, so it would make sense for it to be in the same place by the end of the season.

(Note that contrary to starwars.com's claim, *Rogue One* doesn't actually depict the Death Star as having been constructed over Scarif, but concept art for the film shows that it was planned to be shown at one point.)

The [starwars.com Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/scarif) also describes Scarif as "the principal construction facility for the vast Imperial war machine", though presumably it means this in the general rather than singular sense.